# Lost Control over SSH

Tags: 14.04, ssh

Hi I was trying to edit some settings for ssh on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in /etc/ssh/ssh_config . Somehow unknowingly I did something wrong in the configuration file now I have lost control over ssh connection.Can't connect to the BBB via ssh.

From a different system I can login but not with system. I tried reinstalling the openssh-server and client in a hope to get something working but no luck. Any cues/ help ?

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.7.2 port 22: Connection refused
user@user-VirtualBox:~$ ssh -v root@192.168.7.2
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.7.2 [192.168.7.2] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.7.2 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 192.168.7.2 port 22: Connection refused
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try remove ssh server with:

> apt-get purge

To remove ssh server and any conf files of ssh server, and try reinstall ssh server.